# Type Guard for empty object

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to write a TypeScript type guard that checks if a given object is empty?

I'm able to do the opposite, i.e. write a type guard that checks if an object is *non-empty* (using lodash [isEmpty](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEmpty) here):

```
isNonEmpty<T>(object: T | {}): object is T {
    return !_.isEmpty(object);
}

writeTextIfAny(param: { text: string } | {}): void {
    if (isNonEmpty(param)) {
        console.log(param.text);
    }
}
```

However, when I try to reverse things, something goes wrong:

```
isEmpty<T>(object: T | {}): object is {} {
    return _.isEmpty(object);
}

writeTextIfAny(param: { text: string } | {}): void {
    if (!this.isEmpty(param)) {
        // param is never, not { text: string }
    }
}
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, a TypeScript object type includes any object that has *at least* the specified properties.  That means `{}` is effectively the type of any object.  So if your custom type guard claims that `param` is not a `{}`, then it is not a `{text: string}` either, and you are left with `never`.  (In fact, `T | {}` just simplifies to `{}`, though [maybe it shouldn't quite](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26796).)

I don't believe there's a way to write a type guard for an empty object.  If you say more about how this came up, I might have more suggestions.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the clear concise answer!

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to use `!isNotEmpty(yourVar)` to achieve the behavior you want

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution:

```
guard (self.object != nil) else { return }
```