# Typescript - generic type guard for isEmpty function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I cannot properly implement generic `isEmpty(value)` in terms of narrowing type constrain down of provided value to it's empty counterpart.

Use case:

```
function getCountryNameById(countries: LookupItem[] = [], countryId?: number): string | undefined {

  if (isEmpty(countries) || !isNumber(countryId)) {

    // within this branch I would like to get countries argument to be narrowed to empty array type. 
    // Same would apply for other function which can have argument type of object or string. Why ? -> to prevent someone to do some mad code hacks like accessing non existent value from empty array ( which would happen on runtime ofc ) on compile time
    // $ExpectType []
    console.log(countries)

    return
  }

  // continue with code logic ...
  // implementation ...
}
```

similar case on constraining object:

```
function doSomethingWithObject( data: { foo: string; bar: number } | object ){ 
   if(isEmpty(data)){
     // $ExpectType {}
     data

     // following should throw compile error, as data is empty object
     data.foo.toUpercase()

     return
   }

   // here we are sure that data is not empty on both runtime and compile time
}
```

isEmpty type guard implementation:

```
export const isEmpty = <T extends AllowedEmptyCheckTypes>(
  value: T | AllowedEmptyCheckTypes
): value is Empty<T> => {
  if (isBlank(value)) {
    return true
  }

  if (isString(value) || isArray(value)) {
    return value.length === 0
  }

  if (isObject(value)) {
    return Object.keys(value).length === 0
  }

  throw new Error(
    `checked value must be type of string | array | object. You provided ${typeof value}`
  )
}
```

With defined types:

```
type EmptyArray = Array<never>
type Blank = null | undefined | void

/**
 * // object collects {} and Array<any> so adding both {} and Array<any> is not needed
 * @private
 */
export type AllowedEmptyCheckTypes = Blank | string | object

/**
 * Empty mapped type that will cast any AllowedEmptyCheckTypes to empty equivalent
 * @private
 */
export type Empty<T extends AllowedEmptyCheckTypes> = T extends string
  ? ''
  : T extends any[]
    ? EmptyArray
    : T extends object ? {} : T extends Blank ? T : never
```

It's kinda strange as it's narrowed correctly from type perspective, but not within if/else branch:

[isEmpty for string values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2b7x.png)

[isEmpty for array values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyiV0.png)

[isEmpty for object values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfv3H.png)

code can be seen here: https://github.com/Hotell/rex-tils/pull/13/files#diff-a3cdcb321a05315fcfc3309031eab1d8R177

Related question: [Type Guard for empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52166083/type-guard-for-empty-object)

Comment: I'm having difficulty following this.  Could you include all relevant code here as code (not pictures of code or links to code), remove anything not needed to reproduce the issue, and clearly indicate where your issue is (what you expect vs what you get)?  Providing a [mcve] goes a long way toward getting a meaningful answer.

Comment: If you want a type to be `undefined` if it is an empty object: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgEwgMwJZwggksgogWzFAHkAjAKwgGNgAeM8qCAD2AkQGcoAlagewBOCWgAUBfSANABpCCAA0UAK5wA1nD4B3OAD4dUALwBYAFBRzUANqq5fZFAYBdJq3YIuljADcIA5wH5lRBR0TCgALgcKU1NQSCgAFQgOYABGQ1hgtAxsPEISCmo6AG8AXx1TAHpKiygAPX9Y8GgklIAmDPgkbMwcAiIQBiLaYqgAQwnIgCJSWamocqqaiwbTIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of handling this problem is by separating null checks (`undefined`, `null`) from empty value checks (`''`, `[]` `{}`). I tend to use two type guards for that — `isDefined` and `isEmpty`.

First one may look like this. Note the `typeof` check — this makes it work with undeclared variables as well.

```
function isDefined<T>(value: T | undefined | null): value is T {
  return (typeof value !== 'undefined') && (value !== null);
}
```

For empty values, the following model can be used.

```
namespace Empty {
  export type String = '';
  export type Object = Record<string, never>;
  export type Array = never[];
}

type Empty =
  | Empty.Array
  | Empty.Object
  | Empty.String;

function isEmpty<T extends string | any[] | object>(subject: T | Empty): subject is Bottom<T> {
  switch (typeof subject) {
    case 'object':
      return (Object.keys(subject).length === 0);
    case 'string':
      return (subject === '');
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

type Bottom<T> =
  T extends string
    ? Empty.String
    : T extends any[]
        ? Empty.Array
        : T extends object
            ? Empty.Object
            : never;
```

The bottom values are inferred correctly.

```
declare const foo: 'hello' | Empty.String;
declare const bar: [number, number] | Empty.Array;
declare const baz: Window | Empty.Object;

if (isEmpty(foo) && isEmpty(bar) && isEmpty(baz)) {
  console.log(foo, bar, baz);
}
```

**Edit:** added constraints on `T` as suggested.

Comment: Right, I came close to similar one, only thing that I was missing within the test for the object was explicit type cast of object to union of that object or empty object. I'll use this going forward. many thanks !

Comment: I would also constraint the generic, so consumer get's compile time error if he want's to support non supported isEmpty check type ( it want error on object values, but still better something that nothing I guess :) )    

export const isEmpty = <T extends string | object>(
  value: T | Empty
): value is Bottom<T>

Answer (score 1):

So after a few twitter discussions and long SO/Github search I ended up with following solution:

- first of all checking for null/undefined within a isEmpty doesn't make much sense ( although lodash.isEmpty handles that, IMHO it's doing too much and not in very explicit way )
- because there is basically no difference between `{}` | `object` | `any[]` the type guard narrowing would never work as expected
- final solution accepts only valid values to check as arguments -> js objects and string and guard returns `never` so matching values would be type of `never` because anyway, it doesn't make any sense to execute any further login within `if(isEmpty(value)){ ... }` statement rather then terminate the program or throw an Error

here is the final implementation:

```
const isEmpty = <T extends string | object | any[]>(
  value: T
): value is never => {
  if (isString(value) || isArray(value)) {
    return value.length === 0
  }
   if (isObject(value)) {
    return Object.keys(value).length === 0
  }
   throw new Error(
    `checked value must be type of string | array | object. You provided ${
      // tslint:disable-next-line:strict-type-predicates
      value === null ? 'null' : typeof value
    }`
  )
}
```

https://github.com/Hotell/rex-tils/pull/13/files#diff-68ff3b6b6a1354b7277dfc4b23d99901R50

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
if (isEmpty(countries) || !isNumber(countryId)) {
```

you have two conditions, only one of which is a type guard for `countries`, that's why the type of `countries` doesn't change inside the if.

As for objects, `{}` doesn't represent an empty object. Anything, except for `null` and `undefined`, can be assigned to a variable of type `{}`. You might want to use `{ [prop: string]: never }` or  `{ [prop: string]: undefined }` instead.

Comment: none of those work. I already tried those :)

    { [prop: keyof T]: never } or { [prop: keyof T]: undefined }