# Types check the isEmpty for array or object

Tags: typescript, types

I have an issue when I try to infer that an object is not empty.

**GIVEN**

I have this function getAllListLabels and the custom isEmpty check function.

```
export function getAllListLabels(list: Array<Labels> | undefined) {
  if (isEmpty(list)) {
    return null;
  }
  return list.map((value) => value.label).join(", ");
}
```

```
export function isEmpty<T>(obj: T) {
   if (!obj) {
    return true;
   }
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return isNonEmptyArray(obj);
  }
   return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length === 0;
 }
```

**Problems**
With this isEmpty function my list params compliance when I try to map over because it's possibly still undefined `'list' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)`

**Expected**
I have one uniq function that infer properly that my params if not undefined

**Tries**
I try overloading function without good result, I also try this post with same result [Typescript - generic type guard for isEmpty function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188387/typescript-generic-type-guard-for-isempty-function).

The answer mark as resolve doesn't solve my case because, I would like to keep it in one function.

I solve my case with two separate function, one for array and for object like so but I don't want that.

```
function isNonEmptyArray<T>(obj: T[] | undefined): obj is T[] {
  return (
    obj !== undefined && obj !== null && Array.isArray(obj) && obj.length > 0
  );
}

function isNonEmptyObject<T>(obj: T | undefined): obj is T {
  return (
    obj !== undefined && obj !== null && Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length !== 0
  );
}
```

Comment: `isDefined` can be `false`, (in the case of, say `undefined`, and then it skips the `if` and immediately operates on your `list`, which can error out because it can, as the error says, be `undefined`?

Comment: yes may be a logic error in the playground but my purpose it's to have all this check in one method isEmpty. is that possible?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wEY2kw) meet your needs or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes sorry I remove the playground to avoid poor understanding of my problems. Thanks @jcalz

Comment: @jcalz I'm afraid there's a typo on line 18. It should read `return obj.length === 0;`

Comment: @Valentin yes, thanks

Comment: Ok so your approach is for the truthy value to return all possible case like that for false the type is defintively the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

```
type Falsy = false | 0 | 0n | "" | null | undefined;

function isEmpty(obj: any):
  obj is Falsy | never[] | { [k: string]: never } {
  return !obj || (Array.isArray(obj) && !obj.length) ||
    !Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length;
}
```

This should narrow the input to something "empty".

The first check, `!obj` corresponds to whether or not the input is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), which can only *sort of* be represented in TypeScript.  TypeScript doesn't have a `NaN` [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), as mentioned [in this comment on ms/TS#9407](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9407#issuecomment-229721835), so this function will do unexpected things in the face of `NaN`. The `Falsy` type is just a best effort.

Otherwise we check for an empty array which we give the type `never`, or for an empty object, which we give the type `{ [k: string]: never }`.

I'm sure there are weird edge cases, but this works as expected for your example code:

```
function getAllListLabels(list: Array<Labels> | undefined) {
  if (isEmpty(list)) {
    return null;
  }
  return list.map((value) => value.label).join(", "); // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAMgQwEZQDYGcYF4YG9gwyrJoBcM6IATgJYB2A5gNzAC+LwoksAYghmGwwAZv3SwAPjAAMMKdLpyYAImVK6AV1SolGugBMow+lH0dhegMYgaAe0U10AUQC2EcAApbSAFbkEdGAAlKQEMN4+MI4wfALqUABuUFQA2gC6SrgwKQDW5JS0jGnkdInJMKx4YVRQIBpUigCEEXJSHgCCVFQIYAB0jp3dYF6+QTAAZOMwzb69qFCMIAAWYxISYYSNAPK+UNa9DLVbAO50AApUttBU4AByCC5Q6CM+QXMLDMssrJycFnTWOyKQ4gdraOCOECIFAYDyoSHkQY9AA80LQ6AAfLoDEYTPoxvhCDRhDAPI5XO5hvDKEECRsYDU6g0YJptCxCD9CIz6opqSBei4EBAPB4EvwNFAxlgsWLUBK5iRUG8fLZ6B5lAAaFRBJgwAD0evCOR6bCAA)